# In a mirroring backup profile, what percentage of destination file deletions or changes should raise a red flag?

Tags: backup, mirroring, syncback

Syncback offers a setting to abort an *unattended* mirror backup if a percentage of files will be deleted or changed on the destination.

Here are the settings available.

[image]

I chose the settings shown based on what seems reasonable. Given other settings I see no reason for the source drive to be changed at all; it's a mirror backup, not a two-way sync. I'm seeking wisdom from those here who have more experience with this sort of option (or wish that they had).

Comment: It depends on the details of your data, and when it comes down to it, only you can make that choice.

Comment: So far my choice of 20% has worked except for one instance: I deleted a folder in Downloads that had been created during a Brother MFP installation. Turns out it had over 3,000 files in it, so mirroring that change to the destination triggered a backup abort and warning.